# Visual Studio 2013 Azure Cloud Services Project doesn't see already created Cloud Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to work with my Azure Cloud Service via Visual Studio 2013.  I have connected VS to my Azure account but when I tried to publish the cloud service (brand new project), the wizard doesn't see the already created cloud service.  I have tried signing out and back in, quitting VS, both and still doesn't see the cloud service.  If I try to Create New and use the same name as the already created cloud service I get a DNS name already taken message.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is returned when a cloud service of that name is being used in any subscription, if you're not seeing the cloud service in the dropdown you're probably looking in the wrong place - Ensure that you have selected the subscription in which your cloud service is deployed in the sign-in tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I have ensured I am using the same Azure account.  Look at the screenshots.  I have tried signing out and back in again.  It just doesn't see the cloud service that already exists.

Comment: I don't think the screenshots show which user or subscription you've used in either so I just think it's worth making sure you are using the same user AND subscription.